Use a bash function inside an 'at' job
The at command can be used to schedule jobs for future execution.
This sets up the environment before executing the command, to match that at the time of creating at 'at' job.
However, this does not seem to include bash functions defined in the environment. I have tried exporting a function using "export -f" but this does not show up in the environment created for the at job.
Does anyone know how I could get a function to run in the context of an 'at' job? I know I could convert to a proper command defined in a file, but I'm curious what exactly is stopping the function from being picked up in the environment.
Notably, if one does "export -f myfun" in the environment and then "export -p", the function does not appear in the environment. Is this a bash issue more than anything?
Bash version: GNU bash, version 5.2.21(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

This might help: Can you execute a Bash function with the at command?

at run shell  by default, not bash!! You have to confine your commands into a [tag:bash] script, with a correct shebang. Then you could put everything you want like functions in your script.

Try this: crontab -l | sed '$a * * * * * ( echo "$0 -- $@"; set ) >/tmp/whatsRunByAt.txt' | crontab, wait a minute, then suppress this by: crontab -l | sed '$d' | crontab. Finally look into /tmp/whatsRunByAt.txt! If 1st line do contain /bin/sh -- , this it is not bash.

@Cyrus thanks; this explains the behaviour, good to know it's not a bug but intended behaviour that one has to work around and that there are good reasons for it...

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub this isn't quite the reason for the lack of exported functions ... but you're right, I was totally missing the fact that it's not a bash shell ... despite the big fat warning by at about /bin/sh right at the point of invocation! :D

The script (let's say script.sh) you run with at will be run by atd daemon, and is no more related to your current shell session.
A workaround :
at ... << EOF
/bin/bash << INNER
# Import functions from current session
$(declare -f)
# Run the script
$(cat script.sh)
INNER
EOF


Thanks. Yes I also used something similar in the end (and wrapped 'at' with my own function which does this kind of thing under the hood). Have a look at Cyrus' link above if you're curious to see why they're not allowed in the first place.

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub I'm not sure if that works because #!/bin/bash will be taken as a simple comment, not as shebang.

@Philippe Correct! Syntax would be: at ... < <( echo '/bin/bash <<EoScript';declare -f ;cat script.sh;echo EoScript )
